# shipping promotion for a non selected shipping method

Tags: javascript, commerce-cloud

SFCC Storefront Reference Architecture SFRA shipping promotions.

for a  **selected shipping method** of a lineItemContainer (basket), i can get the active promotions :

```
var PromotionMgr = require('dw/campaign/PromotionMgr');
 var promotionPlan = PromotionMgr.getActiveCustomerPromotions();
var discountPlan = PromotionMgr.getDiscounts(lineItemContainer, promotionPlan);
 var discountsforSelectedMethod = discountPlan.getShippingDiscounts(lineItemContainer.shipments[0]);
```

If there is an excluded product in the lineItemContainer, the promotion does not appear in the list  discountsforSelectedMethod .

---

How can i get this information in JavaScript when the shipping method is not the one selected in the basket ?

```
var promotionPlan = PromotionMgr.getActiveCustomerPromotions();
 var discountPromoShipList = promotionPlan.getShippingPromotions(correspondingShippingMethod);
```

This promotion, that should not be applied for the lineItemContainer, stay in the  discountPromoShipList and this list does not give the information of the excluded product.How can filter this list when the lineItemContainer (basket) contains this excluded item ?

Many thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail.  What is SFRA?  Are you using CommerceCloud?  Please [edit] your post.

Comment: Thank you David for your help. I have tried to clarify my thinking: I hope it is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the promotion configurations have so many options that some are not exposed through the API.

Configurations like excluded/included products are not available in the Javascript API.